# Using recursion within loops -- poor style?

Tags: java, loops, recursion, styles

Simple question, I was just wondering if it was considered poor style to call the method recursively within a loop. I know people have problems with recursion because of its costs of time and space, so I imagine it would be considered even more inefficient and costly to loop AND recur.

Comment: This isn't a question of style, but a question of whether the algorithm is correct or not. If you can make an algorithm that's correct with less complexity, sure, but sometimes you can't. ("Recursion within a loop" doesn't necessarily mean "insane complexity".)

Comment: There is no definitive answer to this question - it really depends on the setup.  Some functions work beautifully by combining recursion and loops, while in other cases it indicates that the program is poorly-written or understood.  I think it's an interesting question, but I don't think this is a good fit for SO's "questions with definitive answers" format.

Comment: I don't see the reason for the downvotes. It's just a normal question where the OP would like to gain some knowledge about a specific thing. Is it becoming a trend to downvote questions for the sake of it?

Comment: Dept is what matters in this case. Recursion is fine so long as you don't run into a stackoverflows.

Comment: "people have problems with recursion because of its costs of time and space" - this is also silly. Compilers can optimize away a lot of it, and the bits they can't probably don't matter outside critical kernels of code.

Comment: @Ali It's a vague, unclear, not really constructive question that doesn't address anything resembling a practical problem. It has no place on SO, even if it is a valid discussion.

Comment: @millimoose what's so vague, unclear and not really constructive about it? The OP is only asking if it is considered poor style to do something specific? What's so vague about asking if some approach is poor style or not?

Comment: @AliAlamiri What's so specific, clear, and constructive about it? "recursion in a loop" isn't specific, it's not an actual algorithm that solves a well-defined problem, the question hasn't occured while writing a program that does anything, it's just two very very broad concepts joined with a preposition without context that would let us answer the question conclusively, instead of with an "it depends". I might as well ask whether "green around orange" is good or not. (It's not if it's green on *an* orange, it's great if you want to get contrasting colours.)

Comment: @millimoose To me it's just a very normal question where the OP just wants to find out if an approach is considered good or bad. This happens a lot in programming and people want to find out if something is considered bad style. I think the question being closed and voted down is just sad and funny. But that's just me.

Comment: @AliAlamiri The OP is free to come back and ask again when he has actual code to show and benchmark results that say it's really slow in practive, and when the answer to his question would be a "Yes" or a "No", or ideally "No, and this is how to do it better". Right now the only answer and comments I see are "maybe sometimes and maybe sometimes not". I mean I'm not even going by some obscure rules from the bowels of [meta], the [FAQ] *starts* with "specific programming problem" and "practical, answerable problems" which this is not, it's asking for a security blanket over a nonissue.

Comment: @millimoose - "when he has actual code to show" - but would that just make for a very localized question which isn't useful to future readers?

Comment: @AliAlamiri - Personally, I voted to close because the question seems to have a slant directed towards style and preference, which seemed potentially argumentative.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Not necessarily. In my experience, questions that get closed as "too localized" are usually of the form "why do I have a compiler error here" and the problem is a typo, or something similarly extreme. I.e. ones where the answer would only be helpful if you had written the exact same code (possibly character for character) as the OP; or ones where there just isn't even a tiny "general" class of problem to address.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I'm new to this forum and just wanted to know. I'll be more specific next time.

Answer (score 6):

Not really - sometimes you have to, for example when recursively crawling a tree data structure:

```
public void crawl(TreeNode node) {
    TreeNode[] children = node.getChildren();
    for(TreeNode child:children) {
        crawl(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Stop following me around online!! Creep!